# Initialization list template variable

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, initialization-list

I tried to look for this on the site but i can't find exactly what I need.
Basically I need to know what is the correct way of initialize a template variable in the default constructor.
Eg.:

```
template<typename T>
class myClass{
   T *arr;        // no problem with this.
   int size;
   int capacity;
   T def_value;   // how do I initialize this template variable in the constructor?
```

I tried something like:

```
myClass(): arr(0), size(0), capacity(0), def_value(0){};
```

But it doesn't compile because I can't assign `0` to, for example, a char (and I know that).
How am I supposed to initialize the `def_value` correctly?

Comment: *i can't assign 0 to, for example, a char (and i know that)* That's not true. You can certainly initialize a `char` with `0`.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it did compile but i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0).

Comment: That's most likely because you didn't initialize `arr` correctly.

Comment: How should i do it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. That will be helpful for potential answerers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I supposed to initialize the `def_value` correctly?

Simply like e.g. this:

```
myClass(): arr(nullptr), size(0), capacity(0), def_value() {};
                                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or this:

```
myClass(): arr(nullptr), size(0), capacity(0), def_value{} {};
                                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept the answer but I can't vote it because my reputation is less than 15.